# Drupal view if record is empty

Tags: list, drupal

I create a view with some filter like content type ="basic page" and more. I just want to know is their an way if my view not give me any record so I display massage to user LIKE

> "No matching record found [click here][1] for similar data."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing a view, on the right under 'advanced', there is a section called 'No results behavior'. Try that.